# python active directory module pyad max returned group members

Tags: python, active-directory, pyad

How can I return all group members if it is over 1500, I'm using below code
Using execute_query member attribute in the group is empty

```
import pyad.adquery
q = pyad.adquery.ADQuery()
q.execute_query(
attributes = ["CN", "sAMAccountName", "sAMAccountType", "name", "title", "distinguishedName", "mail", "managedBy", "member", "memberOf"][::-1],
where_clause = "{0} = '{1}'".format(query_attribute,query_value),
base_dn = "DC=domain,DC=company,DC=net",
)  --> Using execute_query member attribute is empty

result = list(q.get_results())[0]['member'] --> result is None
```

using pyad.from_cn only first 1500 users returned

```
f = pyad.pyad.from_cn('Group Name')
f.get_attribute('member') or f.get_members()  --> both return only 1500 Users
```

Answer (score 1):

This limit doesn't come from pyad, but AD itself. Active Directory will only give you 1500 rows from a multi-value attribute. To get the rest, you have to specifically ask for more.

I haven't tried this in Python, but to ask for the next 1500, you should be able to do something like this:

```
f.get_attribute('member;range=1500-*')
```

Try that and see if it works.

Looking at the [Pyad source code](https://github.com/zakird/pyad/blob/fb2782eef071b57312a414769bf947552f63c080/pyad/adobject.py#L260), that *might* not actually work (because of the `hasattr` check, which might not remove the "range" part when checking if the attribute is valid). There is also [an issue logged for this](https://github.com/zakird/pyad/issues/74), which hasn't been replied to. And since the [project is no longer maintained](https://github.com/zakird/pyad), it's unlikely to get fixed unless you fork it and fix it yourself (it should be as easy as removing that `hasattr` check).

But if that does happen to work, you will have to put that into a loop and keep going until you get an error, which means there are no more results. I have an example in C# [here](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/11/30/find-all-members-of-group.html#single-forest-environments). You can translate the logic in the loop to Python.

Comment: Thank you, I can't find returned query has this attribute member with range, I was able to get all users by reversing the query, by query users that has memberof this group

where_clause = "{0} = '{1}'".format('memberof','group Name')

Comment: The works too! This may not matter to you, but if your environment has more than one domain, you might not get all the results you expect. More info about that here: [Beware of memberOf](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html#beware-of-memberof)